# Updating Form Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have this in my Details View: [UI Snapshot](http://imageshack.us/f/412/captureflo.png/)

This details is coming from the previous page. Now I want to SAVE the changed elements back to DB. How do I do that? I have this on my Home Controller Class:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateItem (Employee model)
    {
        var getEmployee = storeDB.Employees.SingleOrDefault( c=>c.Id == model.Id);
        getEmployee.Name = model.Name.ToString();
        getEmployee.Address = model.Address.ToString();
        storeDB.Employees.Add(model);
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But this is in my Model Class. How do I link up?

Comment: after edit, id would not exist

Comment: I know, because we are not passing ID as params. So do i need to remove the first line then?

Comment: its for update, so you may need first line like this   (c=>c.Id==model.Id)

assuming your model has Id.

Comment: Thanks Bipins. I updated my question and added Id. How should I link this UpdateItem function to the 'Save' button?

Comment: You can create a view with this strongly typed model and scaffold template as Create, but seems like your view is already created, it will create necessary elements. Basically input elements should be created by this model and it should be posted to this same action using http post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HttpPost attribute on your action. All the input fields in your view must be inside a Form, or else the data won't be sent to the action. Once you have that set up, you could use the same model you are using in your view to send the data of your employee to your action. For exemple:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItem (Employee model)
{
    ....
    getEmployee.Name = model.EmployeeName.ToString();
    getEmployee.Address = model.EmployeeAddress.ToString();
    ...
}
```

If you send only the Id then you would have to cycle FormCollection and set the properties of the "getEmployee" entity to the values you are receiving in FormCollection.

Like this:

```
getEmployee.Name = FormCollection["EmployeeName"].ToString();
getEmployee.Address = FormCollection["EmployeeAddress"].ToString();
...
```

And so on. Obviously, Name and Address are the names of the properties of your Employees object.

Are you using EntityFramework? If so, just call the SaveChanges() method of the "storeDB". If not, you have to call the save method of the data access you are using. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Gabo. I edited my question, have a look. Yes! I am using EF 4.1

Comment: Are you Updating or Adding a new entry? I understand you want to Update a row, so the "storeDB.Employees.Add(model);" is not necessary. If you do this you could get duplicated row or an exception telling you that the referential integrity does not allow you to insert a duplicated row. Just use the "storeDB.Employees.Add(model);" only when you want to add a New row.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I want to udpate it, not add another duplicate row to it.

Comment: Then remove "storeDB.Employees.Add(model);" from your code. One more thing, use storeDB.Employees.FirstOrDefault() when working directly with entities. It should work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man, appreciated. How do I link it up to my Save button?

Comment: With your Actions with the HttpPost attribute, your Save button should be and "input" of type "submit" <input type="submit">. that should make a post to the action you explicit, in this case UpdateItem. Use a Helper in your view, it should give you the options to set the action your button needs to execute. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the `Action` as a `HttpPost` and then post the content of the form, build your object based on the form data and then save them.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpPost on the Action method with parameter either the model or FormCollection

If you are passing only the model with values filled in it, model parameter will be better.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItem (Employee model){
//   save model here

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //something like this
}
```

It would be better to use a separate ViewModel for the Employee.

Comment: storeDB.Employees.Add(model);
storeDB.SaveChanges();